# Trying to return empty rows even if data does not exsist in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return the last changed time for a list of users, but i would like to return a row even if the a last changed time does not exist

```
select  user_id, 
        last_changed_time = MAX(ISNULL(change_date_time,0))     
from audit_log_tx
where user_id in (users) 
group by user_id
order by user_id asc
```

Comment: `user_id in (users)` is not valid SQL. (unless that is the name of a column in which case the semantics are probably wrong) What is `users` representing there?

Comment: except for the syntax error Martin Smith already mentioned, the syntax looks valid. Can you share some sample data returing the "wrong" results from your point of view?

Comment: Sorry- I inserted (users) as a place holder for my list of users that im using in my query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
  column_name = COALESCE(MAX(change_date_time), '19000101')
  FROM dbo.users AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.audit_log_tx AS o
  ON u.user_id = o.user_id
  GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Though I really don't like the use of token dates for missing data (especially 0).

Answer (score -1):

use any sql function below

IFNULL(change_date_time,0) or 
COALESCE(change_date_time,0) or
ISNULL(change_date_time,0).
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp [use this link for more details][1]

if users is a tablename this is a clear syntax error.
use

```
select  user_id, 
    last_changed_time = MAX(ISNULL(change_date_time,0))     
from audit_log_tx
where user_id in (select distinct user_id from users) 
group by user_id
order by user_id asc
```

Comment: SQL-Server does not have an `IFNULL` function (the site you link is full of such wrong info.) And your query is basically the same as the OP's. It will not return users without a related row in the audit table.